# Remove duplicates by some condition while processing Spark Dataset

Tags: apache-spark

Drop duplicates by some condition while processing Spark Dataset

I have use case where same dataset fed by two difference systems in different interval with duplicates

example

Assume below is the dataset,

[image]

currently we are producing below output as we are not ignoring any duplicates
[image]

But expected dataset is, as highlighted below duplicates from source ID 567 is priority and should be considered in the final dataset

Tried below solution its works, still want to understand better option as we are dealing joins and  big volume (5lakh rec on each dataset). Better solutions are appreciatable

[image]

```scala
import org.apache.spark.sql.{SparkSession, DataFrame}
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._

val spark = SparkSession.builder().getOrCreate()

val dataset = spark.read.parquet("abfss://path")
dataset.count
val duplicates = dataset.groupBy("y_id").count().filter(col("count") > 1)

val duplicateData = dataset.join(duplicates, Seq("y_id"), "inner")

val filteredDuplicates = duplicateData.filter(duplicateData("c_id") === 2276)
val joinCondition = dataset("y_id") === filteredDuplicates("") && dataset("c_id") === filteredDuplicates("c_id")
val uniqueDataset = dataset.join(filteredDuplicates,joinCondition, "left_anti")
dataset.count
filteredDuplicates.count
uniqueDataset.count
uniqueDataset.show(5000)
```

Comment: `https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/Dataset.html#dropDuplicates(col1:String,cols:String*):org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset[T]`